# How to character-wrap in Android textview without using singleline?

Tags: android, textview

I have a textview in xml file. When a text is set in java file, if the 2nd String is too long, for example: "Hello Worlddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd", the 2nd word is not visible. It should be only one line and should not use the android:singleLine How can I solve it? Thanks in advance for the help. :)

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtItemName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the XML below or refer to this SO [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033012/auto-scale-textview-text-to-fit-within-bounds) as this is what you really need.

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:maxLines="1"/>
```

Comment: It will take another line. @christian

Comment: ahmm. I am avoiding the use of singleLine. (^^;)

Comment: what is your issue with singleLine?

Comment: please try that XML. it will still show the other word and truncate it with ellipsis.

Comment: because I am avoiding not to shrink the text if it's too long.

Comment: this is what you need. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033012/auto-scale-textview-text-to-fit-within-bounds

Answer (score 0):

if you without using singline, you can set height and weight.
**android:scrollHorizontally="false"**

ex :

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
    android:layout_height="15dp"/>
```

Comment: you want same picture ?

Comment: nope. It may be "Guild wwwwwwwwww..." @QuestionAndroid

Answer (score 0):

You can use elipsize property of textview

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/txtItemName"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:maxLines="1"
android:textColor="@color/white"
android:ellipsize="end" />
```

Comment: This will add scroll like property in textView

Comment: cAN YOU give screenshot?

Comment: So, if you put text "Hello Worlddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd" in textview.. It will wrap text what you need is

Comment: It should be "Hello Worldddddddddddd..."

Comment: So, only give `android:ellipsize="end"` and your work is done, provide screenshot also with above text

Comment: Yeah, I don't have problem with ellipsis. My code only shows "Hello..." instead of "Hello Worlddddddddddddd..."

Comment: So, my solution is working right? My solution will show Hello Worlddddddd... perfect..

Comment: The problem is coming because either You must be setting text "Hello" in this textView or you have set `width` of your textview very small which only accomodate _Hello_ in specified width